# Given a regex, how can I know from the pattern what the largest number of fields there are that could be matched?

Tags: java, regex

I need to know, based on the regex itself (without any sample data), what the maximum number of fields it could find is.

For example, for the expression

```
"^(ABC) ?([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6})?(?:(?:/)([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6}))?(?:(?: ?XYZ ?)([0-9]{4}))?$"
```

I'd like some function that would take that as a `String` (or a `Pattern`) and return 4, and would take

```
"^(DEF) ?([0-9A-Z]{1,2})(?:(?:/)([0-9A-Z]{1,2}))?$"
```

and return 3.

It would be simpler if all of these groups were captured, but not all are, and I'd like to avoid having to write my own parser if possible.

Comment: I'd bet dollars to donuts that your question can be reduced to the halting problem.

Comment: @Inerdial Or there could be a simple, 300-character regexp that does it.

Comment: @biziclop "Yo dawg, I heard you like regexp, so I used a regexp on your regexp so you can regexp while you regexp."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very ugly but... seems to do what you need:

```
public class TestRegEx1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^(ABC) ?([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6})?(?:(?:/)([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6}))?(?:(?: ?XYZ ?)([0-9]{4}))?$");
        try {
            Field groupCount = Pattern.class.getDeclaredField("capturingGroupCount");
            groupCount.setAccessible(true);
            int count = ((Integer) groupCount.get(pat)) - 1;
            System.out.println("count : " + count);
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

Or to add the non-reflective version, which depends on `.matcher(String)` being able to reach into the `Pattern` class:

```
public class TestRegEx2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^(ABC) ?([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6})?(?:(?:/)([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6}))?(?:(?: ?XYZ ?)([0-9]{4}))?$");
        int count = pat.matcher("").groupCount(); // it turns out it doesn't matter what pattern you use here
        System.out.println("count : " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: It turns out that you can get this from the `Matcher`, which does almost exactly the same thing. `pat.matcher("").groupCount()` will work, no matter what string you put in as the argument for `matcher`. Thanks, @proactif!